# Redirect facebook request to appstore or google play

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Im sending facebook invitation to my facebook friends through my iOS app. And my friends receives it successfuly.
But when the user clicks on the request i want redirect the user Google Play or App store.
Can anyone help me out with this thanks.

Comment: set url Link in to facebook invitation reqestion.

Comment: im new to this development, can u explain what is facebook invitation reqestion

Comment: go to facebook developer page there you can search facebook invitation url.... just follw the steps..... first u need import fbgraph files...